# GraphQL Filter results by nested object with Hot Chocolate

Tags: c#, graphql, hotchocolate

I have a GraphQL server implemented using Hot Chocolate which is a federated gateway for some other microservices. The gateway server stitches together data from the microservices into a unified response. I have a scenario where the requestor needs to filter the set of results by a nested object.

```
extend type Query {
allWorkOrders(
    first: Int
    after: String
    last: Int
    before: String
    where: WorkOrderFilterInput
    order: [WorkOrderSortInput!]
): AllWorkOrdersConnection @delegate(schema: "WorkOrder", path: "allWorkOrders()")
```

}

```
extend type WorkOrder {
    asset(
        first: Int
        after: String
        last: Int
        before: String
        where: AssetFilterInput
        order: [AssetSortInput!]
    ): AssetConnection @delegate(schema: "Assets", path: "asset(assetId: $fields:assetId, where: $arguments:where)")
    resource: UserConnection @delegate(schema: "Identity", path: "user(id: $fields:resourceUserId)")
}
```

I have tried filtering by passing an additional "where" filter into the AssetConnection, but as expected that filters that property and I end up with an empty array instead of removing the parent object entirely.
I am unable to filter by properties in the asset as the WorkOrderFilterInput has no concept of the extended WorkOrder type.

I have also tried extending the WorkOrderFilterInput without any luck.

What i would like to be able to do is use the extended type (asset) in a filter on the top level WorkOrderFilterInput

```
query{


allWorkOrders( 
    where:{
      and:{
        asset{
          assetName:{
            contains: "test"
        }
        }
      }
    }
  ){
nodes{
  asset{
    nodes{
      assetName
    }
  }
  resource{
    nodes{
      firstName
      lastName
    }
  }
}
```

}
}

Comment: Were you able to figure out a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are searching for is `some`

```
where:{
  asset{
    some: {
      assetName:{
       contains: "test"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

There are some good documentation here
https://chillicream.com/blog/2020/11/18/new-filtering-api